# Lorentz Fitting not guessing well enough

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, modeling

The fitting issue with the Lorentzian plot fitting. On originpro it is fitting good.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import LorentzianModel
import numpy as np


datas = pd.read_csv('pg60_02_0.5V.csv')
a = datas.to_numpy()
a = a.transpose()
x= a[0]
y= a[1]

model = LorentzianModel()
pars = model.guess(y, x=x)
out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x)
print(out.fit_report())
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, '-', label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2X96.png).

Comment: Without trying to be mean, but this is what happens if one uses pre-made functionality without checking the [docs](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#lmfit.models.LorentzianModel) properly. This model seems to have no offset, while the data has.

Comment: Yes thank you, I rectified that problem via adding an offset curve eg. mx+b